# Why are nodes not showing when I add a texture

Tags: materials, node-editor

Ive installed Blender 2.8 and have been trying to find my way around it. I am working on an object and have got to the point where I add Materials. I have node editor up and when I select the object and add a new material, no nodes appear. I have searched multiple links on the internet and none of them have helped me find it. What am I missing and where are my nodes? do they need to be enabled somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have all theese three elements present in your shading window.

[image]

Comment: Ive found it, thank you. I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the Shader editor, the Texture node editor is something else.

Comment: I am not sure where that is, can you point me in the right direction please?